# What is "Interrupt" for transition of a process from running to ready?

Tags: process, operating-system, interrupt

Here is process state diagram from Modern Operating Systems. Transition from running to ready happens when the scheduler picks another process.

[image]

Here is process state diagram from Operating System Concepts. 
What does "Interrupt" mean for transition from running to ready? Is it the same as "the scheduler picks another process" in the above?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: In OS terns, interrupts, both syscalls and actual hardware interrupts to drivers, can cause scheduler runs that can change the set of threads running on the available cores.  Interrupts are the only way that the OS kernel code gets entered at all ,and you must put every effort into understanding this essential knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for a process to transition from the running state to the ready state depending on the OS implements multitasking:

- With [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), the OS uses timer interrupts (there is one timer for each core or processor in the system) to regularly interrupt whatever process is currently running. The interrupt handler then invokes the OS scheduler to determine whether to schedule another process or continue running the same process. If the scheduler decided to run another process, then the current process transition from the running state to the ready state.
- With [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking), the OS does not use interrupts to scheduler processes. Instead, a running process should voluntarily yield control to the scheduler to allow it to schedule another process. So processes do not transition between the running and ready states using interrupts, but only voluntarily.

It seems to me that the figure from the Modern Operating Systems book applies to both multitasking methods while the figure from the Operating System Concepts is specifically about preemptive multitasking. Although by changing the word "interrupt" to something more inclusive like "yield," then the other figure would also apply to cooperative multitasking.